# Cursor with multiple queries in oracle not compiling

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, cursor

I have created a cursor that has two queries joined with inner join, but query is not compiling their is error at the end of first query but the same query is getting executed without cursor.

```
cursor data is
select * from
select rid,id, order from table1
inner join
select pid, name, order from table2
on table1.order =  table2.order
```

original query is much bigger and complicated but end result would be this.

Their are compilation errors at the end of first query and those are generic nature, I guess may be syntax for creating a two joined queries is wrong (this is a wild guess though)

Error:

> SQL statement ignored //at select word of first query
>
> Missing right parenthesis //at the last word of first query

Comment: I advice to you to avoid using of the Oracle reserved words when naming columns : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example based on Scott's schema:

- `SELECT` should contain column aliases if columns returned by those inline views share the same name; otherwise, you won't know which one you're using
- inline views should have their own aliases; basically, that's always a good idea - prefix columns with table aliases, otherwise you'll soon forget which column belongs to which table

---

```
SQL> declare
  2    cursor data is
  3      select a.empno a_empno, b.ename b_ename
  4      from (select empno, ename, deptno from emp) a
  5            inner join
  6           (select empno, ename, deptno from emp) b
  7            on a.deptno = b.deptno
  8      where rownum < 5;
  9  begin
 10    for data_r in data loop
 11      dbms_output.put_line(data_r.b_ename);
 12    end loop;
 13  end;
 14  /
SMITH
JONES
SCOTT
ADAMS

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Good catch and suggestion your answer helped me to the achieve 50% of the answer, rest was able to solve. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to put your subqueries in parenthesis and add aliases for the subqueries:

```sql
cursor data is
select * from
(select rid,id, order from table1) table1
inner join
(select pid, name, order from table2) table2
on table1.order =  table2.order
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, still the same issue.

Comment: Updated the answer should work now - at least it does for me with my testdata...

Comment: Sorry for the late update, Though I have changed the query still the result is same

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer for you, with just small differences and with an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_test(n_test in number)
AS
   CURSOR data 
   IS
      SELECT *
      FROM 
         (SELECT rid
                 , id
                 , "order" or1 
          FROM table1) tab1
          INNER JOIN
          (SELECT pid
                  , name
                  , "order" or1
           FROM table2 ) tab2
           ON tab1.or1 = tab2.or1;
BEGIN
     FOR data_i IN data LOOP
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(data_i.rid);
     END LOOP;
END p_test;
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f575e1f353855b7e7a5915e8c2b3ff34)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but littlefoot answer helped me.

Comment: You are welcome. I just wanted to point out the importance of the Oracle reserved words. I put them under double quotes "".